# DBO return Only one expression can be specified in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table `[_AUX]` receive a value from a asp page (word 'TOJ' was submitted by a form).

Based on this information, I'm trying to create a trigger to update another table called `[dbo].[TODOS]`. 
but i have to select **only one** row randomly that has the 'false' value and then change it to 'true'.

Here's my code:

```
IF EXISTS (
select top 1 A.flag
from [DBO].[_AUX] AS A 
WHERE a.flag = 'TOJ' order by a.ID_AUX desc
          ) 

update DBO.TODOS set DBO.TODOS.[TOJ_FLAG]='true' 
where  DBO.TODOS.[TOJ_FLAG] = 
  (
  select top 1 t.[toj_flag], t.TODOS
  FROM dbo.todos as t
  where t.toj_flag = 'false'
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  )
```

I'm receiving a error from sql management studio:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Use   in statement like this :

```
IF EXISTS ( select top 1 A.flag
            from [DBO].[_AUX] AS A 
            WHERE a.flag = 'TOJ' order by a.ID_AUX desc
          ) 

update DBO.TODOS set DBO.TODOS.[TOJ_FLAG]='true' 
where  DBO.TODOS.[TOJ_FLAG] in
                           ( select t.[toj_flag]
                             FROM dbo.todos as t
                             where t.toj_flag = 'false'
                             ORDER BY NEWID()
                           )
```

Update :

```
update DBO.TODOS set DBO.TODOS.[TOJ_FLAG]='true' 
where  DBO.TODOS.[TOJ_FLAG] in
                           ( select t.[toj_flag]
                             FROM dbo.todos as t
                             where t.toj_flag = 'false'
                           )
```

Comment: the query is not working. when i run the query, i got a error: 

    The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.


but i figure out why. the `select top 1` argument is missing. after fixing this problem, the query runs
but now it's updating all rows to 'true' not only one as expected.

Comment: i gave up. i tried many variations of the code. however the same problems occurs. all rows are updated with 'true'. the random select doesn't work for this query. maybe i found a sql bug or a fault. i will think in another way to do this